# Use nth child in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I would like to select each group of three elements from the first one

Example :

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>2</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>3</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>8</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>9</li> <!-- This one -->
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

So I have to add background one 1, 2, 3; 7, 8, 9; 13, 14, 15, etc ..
I don't have the total amount of `<li>`

Is there a solution using only  nth-child() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution using `nth-child` obviously.

```
li:nth-child(6n+1),
li:nth-child(6n+2),
li:nth-child(6n+3){
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Basicly what 'nth-child' does is making a kind of formula for you. Just replace the 'n' by any number you like to check for which children it will work.

Comment: It works ! But I don't understand ^^ If there're more than 10 product it will works ?

Comment: It will work for any number of children's. No problem